# Can't deploy Angular Universal to Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, express

Whenever I try to deploy my Angular Universal app, the hosting gets deployed without issue, but I'm faced with the following error whenever I run `ng deploy`:

```
Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Everything functions without error when I run `npm run build:ssr` though, so I'm not sure what is causing this error. Here is my `firebase.json` file:

```
{
  "hosting": [
    {
      "target": "iquench-website",
      "public": "dist\\dist\\browser",
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*"
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "*.[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f].+(css|js)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "function": "ssr"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "functions": {
    "source": "dist"
  }
}
```

and my `.firebaserc`:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "default": "PROJECT_NAME"
  },
  "targets": {
    "PROJECT_NAME": {
      "hosting": {
        "iquench-website": [
          "PROJECT_NAME"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are the logs when deploying:

```
=== Deploying to 'PROJECT_NAME'...

i  deploying functions, hosting
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing dist directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged dist (5.72 MB) for uploading
+  functions: dist folder uploaded successfully
i  hosting[PROJECT_NAME]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[PROJECT_NAME]: found 115 files in dist\dist\browser
+  hosting[PROJECT_NAME]: file upload complete
i  functions: current functions in project: backupFirestore(us-central1), deleteUser(us-central1), ssr(us-central1)
i  functions: uploading functions in project: ssr(us-central1)
i  functions: updating Node.js 10 function ssr(us-central1)...
+  scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
!  functions[ssr(us-central1)]: Deployment error.
Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.


Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        ssr

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:ssr"


To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions
Functions did not deploy properly.
```